# Fetch comma seperated value and update as comma seperate value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables. Table1, Table2. I have to get names from Table2 based on some other id's which are common in Table1 and Table2. I have to update Table1 and field name is "Name"

Table1:

```
id    | Name
-------------
a,b,c |
```

Table2:

```
id | Name
------------
 a | dinesh
 b | suresh
 c | ganesh
```

Output in Table1:

```
Id    | Name
-------------------------------
a,b,c | dinesh, suresh, ganesh
```

Comment: Fix your data structure!  Storing multiple values in a comma-delimited column is just not the SQL'ish way to do things.

Comment: Read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is  **Absolutely yes!**

Comment: You were told already, that this is the wrong way to go. Nevertheless, this can be done. Pleae [edit] your question and add the version of SQL-Server (very important!) and your own attempts.

Answer (score 4):

Since you show no attempt at solving this yourself, I will assume you just need to be pointed in the direction of a solution.

One way to approach this is to use a string-split function (there is one built in to SS 2017, but previous versions you had to create one--there are plenty available on this site if you google).

This function will return a table with one row for each of the comma separated values in `Table1`.   Then you JOIN that to `Table2` to get the name and use that to build a comma-separated string with a group-concat function (also built in to SS 2017, but with plenty of examples here about how to do this with earlier versions).

Once you have gotten those values SELECTed, it's a simple matter to generate an UPDATE from that SELECT and update `Table1` with the comma-separated string.